# price area, on product page, is not updating after options were updated

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have added a seperate price block to the product page

```
<block type="catalog/product_price" name="catalog_product_price" template='catalog/product/price.phtml' />
```

For some reason, when I updated the product options, from drop down, the price is not being adjusted, but price does change in the original price area.

Below is a screenshot of the area on the page
http://prntscr.com/fbj6fe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the page having another price box above the price box that I have added. After removing very first price box everything worked fine.